# To get only First matching word only from each string from a list of string?

Tags: string, list, append, unique, matching

```
list_of_string = ["Mumbai Mumbai USA", "Country India America", "Delhi Mumbai USA", "Mumbai India"]
words = ["mumbai", "america", "usa", "delhi","india"]
match = []
def match_words(text, search):
    lower = [x.lower() for x in text]
    f_text = [y for lines in lower for y in lines.split()]
    for text_word in f_text:
        for search_word in search:
            if search_word == text_word:
                if search_word not in match:
                    match.append(search_word)
```

`

#calling the function

```
match_words(list_of_string, words)
```

I want this output:
["mumbai", "india","delhi","mumbai"]
I'm getting this output:
["mumbai","usa","india","america","delhi"]

Comment: India is not even in the list of words that you are trying to match!

Comment: Now added "india" to the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
list_of_string = ["Mumbai Mumbai USA", "Country India America", "Delhi Mumbai USA", "Mumbai India"]
words = ["mumbai", "america", "usa", "delhi","india"]
match = []

def match_words(text, search):
    lower = [x.lower() for x in text]

    for temp in lower:
        f_text = temp.split()
        found = False
        for text_word in f_text:
            for search_word in search:
                if search_word == text_word:
                    match.append(search_word)
                    found = True
                    break

            if (found): break



match_words(list_of_string, words)
print(match);
```